# convergence and integral: a small question

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

For any $t>0$ suppose that $f_t$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and uniformly bounded in $t$ : $\|f_t\|_\infty \leq C$. Suppose that for any $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} f_t(x)g(x) d x \to \int_\mathbb{R} g(x) dx
$$
when $t \to 0$. How show that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f_t(x) \to 1$ when $t \to 0$ ?

I tried to use a function $g=K1_{B(x,r)}$ where $K$ is a constant and where $B(x,r)$ is a small ball around $x$.

Comment: Is $f_t$ uniformly bounded in $t$? Or do you have that $f_t \leq B_t$ where $B_t$ is a constant depending on $t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma shows that $$f_t(x)=1+\sin(x/t)$$is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known theorem:
Let $1\leq p\leq \infty$.  If ${h_n}$ converges in $L^p$ norm to $h$, then
there exists a subsequence $h_{n_k}$ that converges point-wise to $h$.
Notice that you are given an $L^{1}$ convergence of the sequence of functions
$h_{t}:=f_t g$ to the limit function $h:=g$.

Warning: I made a mistake here. The statement above is accurate, but I did not read the question carefully. As @ Sangchul comments:

The question says $\|f_n\|_{L^1}\rightarrow \|f\|_{L^1}$. This is a weaker
condition than convergence in $L^{1}$ norm which is defined by $\|f_n-f\|_{L^1}\rightarrow 0$.

The counterexample given by
@David C. Ullrich. shows that the convergence of norms  $\|f_n\|_{L^1}\rightarrow \|f\|_{L^1}$ does imply point-wise convergence of the sequence $f_{n}$ even after passing to any subsequence.

Comment: As @David C. Ullrich, pointed out, one can construct any number of counterexamples for the point-wise convergence.  The result in my answers guarantees the point-wise convergence of a subsequence (not the sequence itself).

Comment: The OP's condition does not necessarily ensure $L^p$-convergence of $f_t g$ to $f g$.

Comment: Of course. $\|f_n-f \|_{L^1}\rightarrow 0 \Longrightarrow \|f_n\|_{L^1} \rightarrow \|f\|_{L^1}$ but the converse is not true.

Comment: Does this weaker condition imply the point-wise convergence of a subsequence ?

Comment: there is no convergent subsequence in the example in my answer.